# Application stops on changing page

Tags: android, listview

I am working in one application where i am getting continuous response from server but when i change the page or moved to the other screen the application gets stop.I am receiving the response from server but it is not updating in listview.

I have used `onResume` and `onPause` method also but still i am receiving the error.

code;

```
protected class GetTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> {

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                CallReceiveMsgAPIService();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            try {
                if (initiate != 1) {
                    mMessageHandle.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                    new GetTask().execute();

                    }
                } else {


                    mLiveChatList.setAdapter(adapter);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    mLiveChatList.requestLayout();
                                        alert();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

        }
    }
```

error:

```
05-10 14:14:01.213: E/AndroidRuntime(277): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-10 14:14:01.213: E/AndroidRuntime(277): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. [in ListView(2131361857, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class com.$ChatListAdapter)]
05-10 14:14:01.213: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1492)
05-10 14:14:01.213: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchModeChanged(AbsListView.java:1960)
05-10 14:14:01.213: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnTouchModeChanged(ViewTreeObserver.java:591)
05-10 14:14:01.213: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.view.ViewRoot.ensureTouchModeLocally(ViewRoot.java:2021)
05-10 14:14:01.213: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.view.ViewRoot.ensureTouchMode(ViewRoot.java:2005)
05-10 14:14:01.213: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1774)
05-10 14:14:01.213: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-10 14:14:01.213: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-10 14:14:01.213: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-10 14:14:01.213: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-10 14:14:01.213: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-10 14:14:01.213: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-10 14:14:01.213: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-10 14:14:01.213: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

could anybody get me out of this ..@Thanks

Comment: onResume and onPause are empty. What's the need to post it? Posto your logcat and **relevant** snippet of code

Comment: @blackbelt thanks for your response ,i will remove it

Comment: @blackbelt here i have added the error which i am getting while scroll

Comment: you can't update your UI from background thread, make sure you are not doing this

Comment: Now post **relevant** snippet of code

Comment: @juned i have added run on ui thread

Comment: @blackbelt which part of code should i update

Comment: @priya2134412 please add your code snippet

Comment: @priya2134412 can't you move this `new GetTask().execute();` line in `onCreate()` ?

Comment: @juned ok ..i will try but i need to know why this error!!

Answer (score 0):

Call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` after there is a change in the list to notify the `listView` that the contents of list have changed. This will surely solve this error.

```
protected class GetTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> {
public interface TaskListener
{
public void updateResult(Object result);
}
private TaskListener listener;
        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                CallReceiveMsgAPIService();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            try {
                if (initiate != 1) {
                    mMessageHandle.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                    new GetTask().execute();

                    }
                } else {

          listener.updateResult(result);
                    //mLiveChatList.setAdapter(adapter);
                    //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                   // mLiveChatList.requestLayout();
                                      //  alert();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

        }
    }
```

In activity implement this interface TaskListener and in the updateresult method do the code commented.

Comment: Then probably there is some error in your response handling from server, could u add a code snippet to elaborate more.

Comment: you have tried to change the adapter on async thread which is wrong,
Do one thing add a listener and send it back to activity and do the code of else part in that

Comment: same error??  actually i did same thing in one of my app and this worked perfectly..